# How to write a linux kernel module to modify source MAC address of a packet?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, network-programming, netfilter

I want to write a Linux kernel module to modify the source MAC address of a packet that will be sent from my computer.

I have tried `Netfilter` hook at `NF_INET_POST_ROUTING`, but it can only process the L3(IP) header.

I'm looking forward to the L2(MAC) hook funtion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As its name suggests, `NF_INET_POST_ROUTING` is an `INET` layer hook. I think that you need `NF_BR_POST_ROUTING` which lives in `netfilter_bridge.h` ([source](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/netfilter_bridge.h)):

```
/* Bridge Hooks */
/* After promisc drops, checksum checks. */
#define NF_BR_PRE_ROUTING   0
/* If the packet is destined for this box. */
#define NF_BR_LOCAL_IN      1
/* If the packet is destined for another interface. */
#define NF_BR_FORWARD       2
/* Packets coming from a local process. */
#define NF_BR_LOCAL_OUT     3
/* Packets about to hit the wire. */
#define NF_BR_POST_ROUTING  4
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will try this method immediately.

Comment: Hello, if the NIC is not bridged. Then the packets will not go through these hook functions. I want the packets to be processed by the kernel protocol stack, not the bridge. After the kernel protocol stack processes packets, modify the source MAC address of the packet.